# kendo ui editorfor imagebrowser returns 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-403, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to implement the Kendo UI editor with an image browser to insert into the document on an MVC 4.5 page.  the editor is working fine, however, when i click the insert image button i gt a 403 forbidden popup message.

I've created a custom image browser controller pointing to ~/Content/images.
and in my view, i am using the custom browser controller within my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m.QuestionText)
              .Encode(false)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height: 200px" })
              .Name("EditQuestionText")
              .Tools(tools => tools.Clear().InsertImage())
              .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
                  .Image("~/JFA/QuestionImages/{0}")
                  .Read("Read", "JFAImageBrowser"))
     )
```

I've compared my code to the sample project from Kendo for the EditorFor (which will browse the folder) but can find no discernible differences... I also cannot find much in the way of other people who are having this problem so i suspect there is a setting that i cannot find that is causing my issue, any help would be GREATLY appreicated

my image browser (taken directly from the demo)

```
public class JFAImageBrowserController : EditorImageBrowserController
{
    private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/Content/images";
    public override string ContentPath
    {
        get
        {
            return contentFolderRoot;
        }
    }
```

additionally, using Fiddler the click event for the "Insert Image" button is
GET /JFA/JFAImageBrowser/Read?path=%2F HTTP/1.1

where as the demo is 
POST /ImageBrowser/Read HTTP/1.1

I don't know why the demo is using a POST where as mine is using a GET, unless this is because of the overridden image browswer

Answer (score 1):

That code looks fine.  Can you make sure your `JFAImageBrowser` controller looks something like this?

```
public class BlogImagesController : EditorImageBrowserController
{
    //
    // GET: /BlogImage/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public override string ContentPath
    {
        get { return AssetFilePaths.BlogContentPath; }
    }
}
```

It's important that it inherits from `EditorImageBrowserController`

Also, a 403 may mean that the user doesn't have permission to access the directory.  Check the permissions for the user you're running as.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've added my image browser controller to the original post

Comment: the permissions "appear" to be ok.  I even added read/list access for "everyone" and "anonymous logon" to cover everything..

Comment: Try `IUsr` also (it may be called something different on your machine).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem was in the _Layout page. I was using bundling and either 
A) I made some error when setting up the bundling 
-or-
b) the bundling didn't work as expected/intended.
either way i added the individual script/java script references and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem
the page this issue fixed was it kendo forum
http://www.telerik.com/forums/implementing-image-browser-for-editor

and the direct link for the demo
http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/e3e38f54-7bb7-4bec-b637-7c30c7841dd1_KendoEditorImageBrowser.zip?sfvrsn=0

and if this demo didn't work you can see this sample i made from above 
https://www.mediafire.com/?9hy728ht4cnevxt

you can browse the editor through HomeController and the action name is homepage (`home/homepage`)
& I think that the error was in different uses of paths between the base controller & child controller you make.